# KendoUi panel bar and Dictionary

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to bind a dictionary to Keno Ui panel bar? I have looked at the below link. But there is nothing mentioned baout it.

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/panelbar/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that at the moment.

But what you can certainly do is create a '' list dynamically from your dictionary and bind the panelber to that list.

Let me know.

Comment: I had it working with lists. But wanted to know if it supports dictionary for soem other reason. Looks like it doesn't.